# "Doubleclick to minimize enabled" prompt on Mac - how to disable it?

Tags: mac, window-manager

In my Mac settings, I enabled doubleclick on window title to minimize. And it works.

But, randomly I get this incredibly annoying prompt asking me if I want to revert to default:

[image]

NO, I don't want to revert, I enabled it - because I wanted to.

How to disable this prompt? It just starts popping randomly :(

Answer (score 8):

That popup is from the third-party tool BetterSnapTool.

This app provides its own functionality for the title bar double-click, which conflicts with the macOS functionality.

If you want to use the macOS functionality you enabled, disable the functionality in BetterSnapTool or uninstall the app entirely.

Comment: maybe just maybe add how he can find that software?